# Should I replace this stator? (2007, Suzuki, DL1000)

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, generator

I opened my stator case to inspect what I thought was a bad stator. I discovered the following issues with my magnets:

Broken Magnets:
[image: broken-magnets]

Cracked Magnets:
[image: cracked-magnets]

Not sure if I need to replace stator (already have a new one though)
[image: stator-highlights]

Based on the fracture lines in the magnets, I think I need a new set (??). I expected that I might have loose magnets so I bought some JB Weld but this set looks like a total loss to me. I am not sure where to buy a set of magnets. Do I really need to replace this stator (given its current condition). What should I use to clean the stator and internal gears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnets on your stator actually unglued from the rotor. You should be able to remove them by hand.

I think this is a known problem on dl1000, although i never had this problem with my k2 (yet). I don't know if they can be glued back, but you can buy a new rotor for sure.

Comment: Yep. That is what I decided to do. A new rotor is on order and I'll hang onto the spare magnets in case of future issues. It's a bit of a pain as the bike only has ~14.5k miles on it. Thanks for the feedback.